# Swift Remove Text

Tags: swift, swift3

I need help removing text within parentheses and brackets.

```
"Hello - Adele (Cover)" -> "Hello - Adele "
"Flo Rida - Wild Ones ft. Sia [Official Video]" -> "Flo Rida - Wild Ones ft. Sia"
"Hello - Adele (Cover) [Video]"
```

Comment: I've edited my answer to match your edit with a 3rd example.

Answer (score 2):

```
let text = "Hello - Adele (Cover) [Video]"

var set = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "([")
var comps = text.components(separatedBy: set)
let arr = comps.filter({ !$0.contains(")") && !$0.contains("]") })

arr[0] // "Hello - Adele"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression:

```
let text = "Hello - Adele (Cover) - Flo Rida - Wild Ones ft. Sia [Official Video]"
let pattern = "\\s(\\[.+\\]|\\(.+\\))"
let filteredText = text.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: "", options: .regularExpression) // "Hello - Adele - Flo Rida - Wild Ones ft. Sia"
```

The pattern is: *A whitespace character followed by **either** a left bracket, one or more arbitrary characters and a right bracket **or** a left parenthesis, one or more arbitrary characters and a right parenthesis.*