# Avoiding unterminated swift literal

Tags: swift

I am trying to delete the words that are included in closed brackets. for ex `ha]I blah` will be `I blah`

To do this below is my code.

```
var comps = ["", "test] \n\"Look"]
let arr = comps.filter({ !$0.contains("] \n\") })
print(arr) //should out put ["","Look"]
```

however I am getting an unterminated string literal error at `let arr`.
Is there any workaround to this problem?

Comment: \” is an escaped quote. You probably didn’t mean to include the \ in your contains.

Comment: hi, `"] \n` does work but doesn't strip the string

Comment: why the output should be `["look"]`? There is no element `"look"` in the original array.

Comment: @LeoDabus sorry updated my q should be `["","Look"]`

Comment: `filter` won't mutate the array elements

Comment: @LeoDabus however when I try to implement this code it works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39946198/swift-remove-text

Comment: Why would you expect it to remove `"test"` from it as well? It is not a regex.

Comment: @Satsuki What are you expecting to happen to "`test`"?

Comment: In your example `ha]I blah`, "ha" is not enclosed in brackets. Why should it be stripped? Explain the requirements better, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map your collection of strings and replace all occurrences in your string that matches your requirement and whatever comes in front of it using a regular expression:

```
var comps = ["", "test] \n\"Look"]
let target = "] \n\""
let arr = comps.map {
    $0.replacingOccurrences(of: "^.*\(target)", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
}
print(arr) // "["", "Look"]\n"
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! First time using the map function. will study more..